# Equivalent of tabpanel's ._hide() in C#

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabpanel

I'm almost sure I've done this before, but I can't find it anywhere...

I have 3 tabs in an ajax TabContainer and 2 CheckBoxes outside. All 3 tabs are visible unless both the CheckBoxes are unchecked, in which case the 3rd tab should be hidden.

I can show/hide in javascript when the checkbox values are changed

```
    $find('<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[2]._hide();
    $find('<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[2]._show();
```

but on PageLoad, I can't get it to work with C#. I tried setting display and visibility, but neither hid the tab. The only thing that worked was setting Visible=false, but if I do that the tab isn't rendered at all and the javascript can't show it later.

**EDIT:**
I tried registering the same script in PageLoad, but still doesn't work

```
    string script = "<script type=text/javascript> $find('<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[2]._hide(); </script>";

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    String csname1 = "TabScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, script);
```

OptionsTabs is null here.

I tried sending the ClientID I get server side. 
I tried sending the tab name instead of the tabcontainer name. 
I tried setting the display/visibility of the tab and tab header. Nothing worked.

Comment: Can't u generate same JS code via something like `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` in your ASP.NET/C# code?

Comment: Would have to trigger it. Hoping for something simpler.

Comment: What do you mean trigger? It will run automatically after page load.

Comment: Just tried adding it with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, but it throws a null reference exception when trying get_tabs.

Comment: You mean in client code? $find doesn't find anything?

Comment: Yes, $find('<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>') returns null or undefined

Comment: Don't use `<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>`. Get actual ClientID server-side. Can you plz post C# code that you're using for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string script = "$find('" + OptionsTabs.ClientID + "').get_tabs()[2]._hide();";
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
String csname1 = "TabScript";
Type cstype = this.GetType();
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, script, true);
```

As an alternative, since you're using MS Ajax and it has page lifecycle for client-side as well you can try `Load` event in JavaScript, add this to *clinet-side* code:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(appLoaded);

function appLoaded(sender, eventArgs) {
   $find('<%=OptionsTabs.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[2]._hide();
}
```

Comment: Same null reference error: Unable to get property 'get_tabs' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Apparently control is not yet initialized at the time of this call. I've updated my answer with client-side alternative